# eclipse crash every couple of minutes, need help

Tags: eclipse, crash, windows-7-x64

Eclipse Helios installed on windows 7 pro 64 bit system, it crash once every couple of minutes, it used to work fine, but recently get worse, I am afraid that I may have some configuration error, but it appears the solution from google didn't apply to me.
  Need help, thanks.

Note:

Error message like this:

java

Comment: Not much of a programming question. Try uninstalling last windows updates

Comment: Do you have the 64-bits version of Eclipse with a 64bits version of the JDK? and does [this `eclipse.ini`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) improve the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Maby you hit [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333227) in 64-bit JRE? Try [this workaround](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333227#c7).